# how to escape star in bash variable used for program arguments

Tags: bash, escaping, glob

I have a variable that has program arguments to my `java` command with the classpath to include all jars in a directory, but I am not able to escape the asterisk correctly so keep getting `main` class not found error.

Here are few examples. lib/ contains all my jars. `test.Main` contains `main()` class.

Inline works as expected:

```
java -classpath lib/* test.Main
```

However, all these attempts failed:

```
# 1)
PRARGS="-classpath lib/*" test.Main
java $PARGS

# 2)
PRARGS="-classpath lib/*" test.Main
java "$PARGS"

# 3)
PRARGS="-classpath lib/\*" test.Main
java $PARGS

# 4)
PRARGS="-classpath lib/\*" test.Main
java "$PARGS"
```

Comment: Don't save program arguments in regular variables, use arrays instead.

Comment: the framework doesn't allow using arrays. I can only set the program arguments in a variable. Also, there are many arguments including JVM args, etc. Is there no way to escape the asterisk?

Comment: No, there is no way to make this work by quoting or escaping the value or expansion. You will have to figure out the constraints of your framework and then adapt the value and/or commands. It's trivial to fix from the bash point of view

Comment: you just did not quote the whole string. repeat # 1-4) with and without noglob (see @Philippe answer)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to escaping star is to disable path expansion.

Try this:

```
PRARGS="-classpath lib/* test.Main"
set -o noglob
java $PRARGS
set +o noglob
```